# Как с радио кнопками сделать таб

Tags: javascript, css, tab

Есть две радио кнопки, надо сделать из них таб.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="my_b btn">
     <input type="radio" name='gender1' >
     <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i> 
     <span>Tab 1</span>
     </label>

    <label class="my_b btn active">
     <input type="radio" name='gender1' checked>
     <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
     <span>Tab 2</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```css
label {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 57px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.tab1, .tab2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.tab1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.tab2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#tab1:checked ~ div.tab1,
#tab2:checked ~ div.tab2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="tab1" class="my_b btn">Tab 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="tab1" name='gender1' >
     
<label for="tab2" class="my_b btn active">Tab 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="tab2" name='gender1' checked>
    
<div class="tab1">
  Это содержимое таба номер 1
</div>

<div class="tab2">
  Это содержимое таба номер 2
</div>
```

Comment: у Вас не такие кноаки!

Comment: @OlmerDale в смысле, не такие? ) <input type="radio" id="tab1" name='gender1' > Ровно такие как в вопросе, я только id им добавил

Comment: У Вас кнопки, а автору нужны кноаки!

Comment: с радио кнопками никак?

Comment: Это и есть с радиокнопками ))

Comment: ok Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

вот так сделал но не получилось!!!

```
               <div class="btn-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label for=tab1 class="my_b btn" id="tab1">
                  <input type="radio" name='gender1'  id="tab1">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x" id="tab1"></i> 
                  <span>tab 1</span>
                </label>
                <label for=tab2 class="my_b btn active" id="tab2">
                  <input type="radio" name='gender1' id="tab2" checked>
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x" id="tab1"></i>
                  <span>tab 2</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="tab1">text 1</div>
            <div class="tab2">text 2</div>

            #tab1:checked ~ .tab1,
            #tab2:checked ~ .tab2 {
                display: block;
            }
            .tab1,.tab2 {display: none;  }
```